# How to stop threads once variable has been set to false?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, boolean

How do I stop all threads from executing further once my boolean variable has been set to false? For example, here's a simple code:-

```
class testing implements Runnable{
   static boolean var;
   int id;
   public void run(){
      System.out.println(id);
      var = false;
   }
   testing(int id){
      this.id = id;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int i = 1;
      var = true;
      while(var){
         new Thread(new testing(i++)).start();
      }
   }
}
```

I want to print only "1", but when I execute this code, I get multiple numbers. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Because the while loop is executed several times before the (new) threads are actually started .The thread for main function is running for some time creating threads before it yields execution to other thread. By calling ```start()``` you tell the thread to start, but it is the scheduler who decides when a thread shall start. You might give a try to the ```Thread.currentThread().yield()``` method to make way to the newly created thread.

Comment: Are you suggesting I do Thread.sleep() in the while loop?

Comment: You probably should use a completely different approach. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sleep() or yield()... either way will let the main thread out. Note that yield() docs say *The scheduler is free to ignore this hint.*

Comment: General rule of thumb: if you find yourself needing to call a "sleep()" in a thread - you've probably got a poor design.  "Sleep()" is a warning that you're probably doing something unnecessary, or something wrong...

Comment: I'm trying to implement a concurrent TCP client-server system using threads. When any client types "terminate", the server denies requests from new clients. In my code, when that string is encountered, a boolean value is set to false and thus those threads aren't made.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that in Java, because Java does not have properties like C# does for example. The best solution in java is to do this:

```
public void setMyVariable(boolean v) {
    var = v;
    // code to stop executing threads
}
```

However, if you **still want to make it the way you want**, there is a much worse way to do that:

Create a new thread, and run this code:

```
boolean run = true;
while(run) {
    if (!var) {
        // code to stop your threads
        run = false;
    }
}
```

But keep in mind, the 2nd way shouldn't really be your option. It is *much better* to stick with the first method.